# Shaking single tile in java (libgdx + TiledMap)

Tags: java, libgdx, tile

I'm making a clone of old Super Mario and I am trying to shake the brick tile when mario in his little form hits it from below. The concept is taken from a great libgdx tutorial by Brent Aureli and everything he wrote/shown works, however when I made this (seemingly small) modification, the modification itself behaves strange.

Namely, when little mario hits the tile (any brick tile) ALL tiles of this kind get this offset. From my understanding, the access is `getCell().getTile().setOffsetY(value)` which should mean

get a single cell -> get tile in that cell -> set offset to this one tile that is in the given cell.
Documentation also suggests it should work like that:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/

replacing tile with null when big mario hits the tile works as intended, so I don't understand why the approach with getCell.getTile doesn't.

Finally, I'm aware that cells are immobile, all I want is a purely cosmetic shift of the actual texture for half a second or so - and that is possible, but in the current state it offsets ALL similar tiles.

For the fun of it I

```
    public class Brick extends InteractiveTile {

    private static TiledMapTileSet tileSet;

    public Brick(PlayScreen screen, MapObject object) {
        super(screen, object);
        tileSet = screen.getMap().getTileSets().getTileSet("tileset_gutter");
        fixture.setUserData(this);
        setCategoryFilter(SuperMario.BRICK_BIT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHeadHit(Mario mario) {
        if(mario.isBig()){
            SuperMario.manager.get("audio/breakblock.wav", Sound.class).play();
            setCategoryFilter(SuperMario.DESTROYED_BIT);

            getCell().setTile(null);
        }
        else {
            SuperMario.manager.get("audio/bump.wav", Sound.class).play();
// DOES THE EXACT SAME AS LATER 3 LINES
//            getCell().getTile().setOffsetY(2);

            getCell().setTile(tileSet.getTile(28)); //this can change texture of individual tile.

            TiledMapTile tile = getCell().getTile();
            tile.setOffsetY(2);
            getCell().setTile(tile);
        }

    }
}
```

InteractiveTile:

```
public abstract class InteractiveTile {

    private World world;
    private TiledMap map;
    private TiledMapTile tile;
    private Rectangle bounds;

    protected Body body;
    protected final Fixture fixture;
    protected PlayScreen screen;
    protected MapObject object;


    public InteractiveTile(PlayScreen screen, MapObject object){
        this.screen = screen;
        this.world = screen.getWorld();
        this.map = screen.getMap();
        this.object = object;
        this.bounds = ((RectangleMapObject)object).getRectangle();

        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        bdef.position.set(
                (bounds.getX()+ bounds.getWidth()/2)/ SuperMario.PPM,
                (bounds.getY() + bounds.getHeight()/2)/SuperMario.PPM);
        body = world.createBody(bdef);
        shape.setAsBox(
                (bounds.getWidth()/2)/SuperMario.PPM,
                (bounds.getHeight()/2)/SuperMario.PPM);            fdef.shape = shape;
        fixture = body.createFixture(fdef);
    }

    public abstract void onHeadHit(Mario mario);

    public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell(){
        TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(1);
        return layer.getCell(
                //REVERT SCALING (PPM) AND by tile size
                (int)(body.getPosition().x * SuperMario.PPM / 16),
                (int)(body.getPosition().y * SuperMario.PPM / 16));
    }

    public void setCategoryFilter(short filterBit){
        Filter filter = new Filter();
        filter.categoryBits = filterBit;
        fixture.setFilterData(filter);
    }
}
```

is there an error in this code, or it is a limitation of the engine?

PS - the original (unmodified)files can be found on Brent Aurelis github site:

https://github.com/BrentAureli/SuperMario

Comment: Tile instances are shared across all cells (for memory conservation purposes). The documentation doesn't suggest that each cell contains or returns a copy of the original tile.

Comment: so in other words, it's not possible to access a single tile/texture. I guess I'll have to look for a workaround - Thanks. I was expecting that while tiles share texture itself, the individual tiles could be manipulated just as I can change texture for a single tile.

Comment: You can, if you choose, subclass the loader and have it create copies of the tiles if you like. You can also iterate over the cells and do the same. Alternatively, you can use cell subclasses that have offsets and a custom renderer that can get offsets from the cell.

Comment: I think I'll try with custom loader - seems like that would need less cycles than iterating through each and every cell - thanks for suggestions!